# Remote Server returns error 401 Unauthorized Webexception (POST)

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm trying to solve an issue that I Mostly (70%) have (30% is succesfull).

I trying to do a webrequest (POST) with the following code:

```
private string HttpWebRequest(string busStopCode)
    {
        //XML input
        string xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?><Siri version='1.0' xmlns='http://www.siri.org.uk/'><ServiceRequest>                              <RequestTimestamp>2011-10-24T15:09:12Z</RequestTimestamp><RequestorRef><username></RequestorRef><StopMonitoringRequest version='1.0'>                                 <RequestTimestamp>2011-10-24T15:09:12Z</RequestTimestamp><MessageIdentifier>12345</MessageIdentifier><MonitoringRef>"+busStopCode+"</MonitoringRef></StopMonitoringRequest></ServiceRequest></Siri>";
        string responseFromServer = null;

        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://<username>:<username>@nextbus.mxdata.co.uk/nextbuses/1.0/1");
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";

        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        string postData = xml;

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();



        // Get the response.

        WebResponse response = null;

        while (response == null)
        {
            try
            {
                response = request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }


        // Display the status.
        MessageBox.Show(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription + " Completed");

        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        // Read the content.
        responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        return responseFromServer;

    }
```

When I call this function I get mostly a messagebox of my exception with:

```
"System.Net.WebException: The remote Server returned an error(401) not authorized with System.Net.Http.Webrequest.GetResponse() with WindowsFormApplication1.Form1.HttpWebRequest(string BusstopCode) in <my pathfile>...."
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I already tried several solutions from previous threads but without success...

Thanks!

Comment: So what requests succeed and which ones fail? Perhaps request type X always succeeds and request type Y always fails? On the face of it, your code looks okay. So there must be something the server doesn't like.

Comment: No it's not like that.
It's just sometimes when I run the application that my program succeeds and I get a response back (30%) but the other 70% it fails...